# Terraform for-each with map of objects and a list

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I would need to have implemented nested for-each loop to define service accounts `map(object)` what are planned to get created and also what key users `visibility` will have an access to a secret stored in Azure Key Vault set for RBAC containing it's passwords

I checked multiple articles and tried to apply them however failed to make it work.
The problem here is to get to individual `principal_id` when for-each is there already in place

Variable definition:

```
variable "user_collection" {
  type = map(object({
      name       = string,
      role       = string,
      namespace  = string,
      warehouse  = string,
      ## What user (ObjectID within AAD should have access to generated password)
      visibility = list(string)
    }))
}
```

Values provision, here I am trying to provide access to user's password to two people:

```
module "SVC_USERS" {
  source              = "./user-module"
  user_collection   = {
    user_1 = {
    name       = "TEST_SVC_1"
    namespace  = "ADMINISTRATION"
    role       = "PUBLIC"
    warehouse  = "ADMIN_WH"
    visibility = ["b9ad7db3-ea64-4815-aad5-a5a72b5bbee9", "d634ebdf-6928-427c-9678-fc3bad8eccc4"] 
  }
 }
}
```

Setting up of role based access to the created secret

```
# Provide access to see generated passwords for key users
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "secret_access_provision" {
  for_each             = var.user_collection
  scope                = "${module.variables.keyVault-id}/secrets/${replace(each.value["name"] , "_", "-")}"
  role_definition_name = "Key Vault Secrets User"
  principal_id = each.value.visibility
}
```

Comment: How many principal IDs can be defined?

Comment: I am not expecting more than 3 per each user's secret

Comment: I meant is the argument able to use lists.

Comment: No, this argument cannot use list (sorry for initial misunderstanding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, I believe you need to [flatten](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/flatten) the product of the user objects with each visibility id. You can do so like this, I believe.

*note:* I have shown an abbreviated version of the `user_collection` as a local, but you can replace `local.user_collection` with `var`.

```
locals {
  user_collection = {
    user_1 = {
      name       = "TEST_SVC_1"
      visibility = ["b9ad7db3-ea64-4815-aad5-a5a72b5bbee9", "d634ebdf-6928-427c-9678-fc3bad8eccc4"]
    }
  }

  user_vis = flatten([
    for user, cfg in local.user_collection : [
      for id in cfg.visibility : {
        user = user
        cfg  = cfg
        id   = id
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "secret_access_provision" {
  for_each = { for uv in local.user_vis : "${uv.user}-${uv.id}" => uv }

  scope                = "${module.variables.keyVault-id}/secrets/${replace(each.value.cfg.name, "_", "-")}"
  role_definition_name = "Key Vault Secrets User"
  principal_id         = each.value.id
}
```

Where you will get one `azurerm_role_assignment` per user / visibility combination.

---

Since, I cannot get test azure outputs for clarification, I created this output for illustration.

```
output "user_vis" {
  value = { for uv in local.user_vis : "${uv.user}-${uv.id}" => uv }
}
```

Which gives:

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + user_vis = {
      + user_1-b9ad7db3-ea64-4815-aad5-a5a72b5bbee9 = {
          + cfg  = {
              + name       = "TEST_SVC_1"
              + visibility = [
                  + "b9ad7db3-ea64-4815-aad5-a5a72b5bbee9",
                  + "d634ebdf-6928-427c-9678-fc3bad8eccc4",
                ]
            }
          + id   = "b9ad7db3-ea64-4815-aad5-a5a72b5bbee9"
          + user = "user_1"
        }
      + user_1-d634ebdf-6928-427c-9678-fc3bad8eccc4 = {
          + cfg  = {
              + name       = "TEST_SVC_1"
              + visibility = [
                  + "b9ad7db3-ea64-4815-aad5-a5a72b5bbee9",
                  + "d634ebdf-6928-427c-9678-fc3bad8eccc4",
                ]
            }
          + id   = "d634ebdf-6928-427c-9678-fc3bad8eccc4"
          + user = "user_1"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tested and it works well, if I understand the implementation correctly then this means that I will have to define new user from now on both in root module where variable `user_collection` is getting called and also within local in `user` module, is there a way to avoid this double specification and ideally not needing this local variable at all so that all variables are needed to be defined in root module only?

Comment: As I say in the note, the `local.user_collection` is just to simplify the illustration. You would remove this local entirely and reference `var.user_collection`, but you need `local.user_vis` still. It is only the once though.

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing this one out and providing the solution to me